# C#, Emgu webcam - choose capture size

Tags: c#, video-capture, emgucv

I'm using the Emgu library for integrating the open CV webcam features in C#.

I use this code for choosing the capture device and setting its size:

```
camera = new Capture(0);
camera.SetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, videoSettings.width);
camera.SetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, videoSettings.height);
```

Then I display it in an imageBox like this: `imageBox1.Image = camera.QueryFrame();`

Then to capture a snapshot of the current frame I use this code:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> snapshot = camera.QueryFrame();
snapshot.Save("snapshot.jpg");
```

Though I would want to be able to save the snapshot at a higher resolution than the preview window.

But the problem is that as far as I know I can't create a new "Capture" object using the same webcamera. So I'm wondering if it is maybe possible to set the `camera.setCaptureProperty` height and width to let's say 1028x720 but then in some way crop it for displaying it in the imageBox with the resolution of 514x360?

Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: For those wondering where `CAP_PROP` is defined, it's in `Emgu.CV.CvEnum`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this by using

```
imageBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using the **Resize()** method in **QueryFrame()**

```
currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
```

Comment: This works, but it still seems to crop some of the image.  Use the imageBox.SizeMode instead.